Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a positive decreasing sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}na_{n}$ goes to 0. Does it follow that $\sum a_{n}$ converges?
Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a positive decreasing sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}na_{n}$ goes to 0. Does it follow that $\sum a_{n}$ converges?
Thoughts
I managed to solve the converse of it. But am not able to do it, or find a counter example. Help.

Try $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log n}$.

oh yes, it diverges.

@Mark Why not an official answer?
